# Upgrade EC2 instance (ubuntu) without losing IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know I can associate an instance with an Elastic IP. However, is it possible to "reserve" or transfer over a current public IP that an instance has so that it can be used when I upgrade the instance?

Comment: You mean a public IP that you have outside of AWS or a public IP associated with a running instance that is not from an attached elastic IP?

Comment: @MikeBrant the latter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.  The only way you can guarantee a specific IP to an instance is via use of elastic IP.  So you would have to have that previously attached to the running instance, shut the instance down for size upgrade, then re-attach the elastic IP to the new instance.

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that this server can forward requests to another instance? Oh man this means I have to change all my API calls

Comment: Can you not solve this problem via DNS? Get new ip for new server, then make DNS cutover, allowing both servers to run until propagation is completed.

Comment: I just ended upgrading to a whole new instance using the elastic IP. only took a few hours to get everything situated again... too quiet ahah